# Why isn't conversion from dp to px precise?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, pixel, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I'm trying to draw a black rectangle that covers the yellow `Box` `composable`, After converting the `size` to `pixels`. The `Box` is still slightly visible underneath. Is there a way around this?

```
val size = 50.dp
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(size)
        .background(color = Color.Yellow)
        .drawWithContent {
            val sizePx = size.toPx()
            drawRect(
                color = Color.Black,
                size = Size(width = sizePx, height = sizePx)
            )
        }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `size` parameter inside `drawRect`

Comment: Interesting... Differential Diagnosis people!

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sir, that's not what the question is about. It is about how the conversion seems to be erroneous.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper I know. I can't replicate the issue with `1.3.0-beta01`, in any case to draw a black rectangle that covers the yellow `Box` composable it is not needed to use the `size` parameter inside `drawRect`.

Answer (score 1):

Dp to px conversion is `dp.value * density` and it's precise. However Modifier.layout or Layout returns dimensions in Int while conversion `dpSize.toPx()` and you can use `dpSize.roundToPx()` for Int conversion.

On my device

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val dpSize = 50.dp
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(dpSize)
        .background(color = Color.Yellow)
        .drawWithContent {
            val sizePx = dpSize.toPx()
            text = "drawWithContent: density: $density, dpSize in px: $sizePx, drawScope size: ${size.width}\n"
            drawRect(
                color = Color.Black,
                size = Size(width = sizePx, height = sizePx),
            )
        }


) 

Text(text = text)
```

[image]

When you draw anything inside DrawScope if you are going to draw anything that covers your Composable you don't need to pass a size.

You can use DrawScope.size. Same goes for pointerEvents either. inside pointer scope and draw scope you can get size without any extra work.

The issue you faced might be a preview bug. Even if it wasn't precise size you get from conversion is bigger than Composable size